# Filtering accounts from two different OUs in django-python3-ldap

Tags: python-3.x, django, active-directory, ldap

We have a django project, where users get to login using their local AD access using [django-python3-ldap](https://github.com/etianen/django-python3-ldap). This has worked fine, since we have been using only one OU until now. However, we now need to get users from other OU, which is at the same level as the current OU. How can we do this?

We have setup following:

settings.py

```
# The LDAP search base for looking up users.
LDAP_AUTH_SEARCH_BASE = 'DC=ypn,DC=local'
# Custom setting
LDAP_AUTH_FORMAT_SEARCH_FILTERS = 'project.ldap.custom_format_search_filters'
```

ldap.py:

```
from django_python3_ldap.utils import format_search_filters

def custom_format_search_filters(ldap_fields):
    # Call the base format callable.
    search_filters = format_search_filters(ldap_fields)
    # Advanced: apply custom LDAP filter logic.
    search_filters.append('(|(OU=office1)(OU=office2))')
    # All done!
    return search_filters
```

And when we run python .\manage.py ldap_sync_users, it just gives us nothing. I know the filtering works, because I can search by names, for example (sn=name), and it will give me correct results.

Running search without any filters just results on lots of "junk" accounts, people that have left, computers, etc. and we don't want to bring all that junk onboard.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you figured this out yet but it looks like you are trying to sync users in an OU rather than a group. You are so close on this one.

for example, if you group names are office1 and office2 you would do this:

```
def custom_format_search_filters(ldap_fields):
    # Call the base format callable.
    search_filters = format_search_filters(ldap_fields)
    # Advanced: apply custom LDAP filter logic.
    search_filters.append('(|(CN=office1,OU=DistributionGroups,DC=domain,DC=com)(CN=office2,OU=SomeOtherOUOrEvenTheSameOU,DC=domain,DC=com))')
    # All done!
    return search_filters
```

I just went through the same issue you were having and discovered i needed the contextual name rather than the group name on its own.